# How do I add this extra stipulation (or condition) in mysql select?

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have this select statement, which works. It makes sure user has access to the job via the user's group id.

```
SELECT jobs.*, user_table.* 
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN user_table ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid
WHERE jobs.groupid = ".$_SESSION['usergroup']."
AND jobs.id = $id
AND (approved = 1 OR approved = 2 OR approved = 4);
```

I added a table column and in this new table column for each job will be extra authorized users to the job.  it will be saved in a comma separated format with user id's (not group id's).  so on top of having access to user's own company jobs via group id, now i want to allow access to any user that is in comma separated list via userid.  here are some attempts i tried that do not work.  with all of these, it doesn't break the original functionality to have access to own company jobs, but it's not giving access to other jobs where the user's id is in the new extra_auth_users column.

```
//try 1
SELECT jobs.*, user_table.*
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN user_table ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid
WHERE (jobs.groupid = ".$_SESSION['usergroup']." OR ".$_SESSION['userid']." IN (jobs.extra_auth_users))
AND jobs.id = $id
AND (approved = 1 OR approved = 2 OR approved = 4);

//try 2
SELECT jobs.*, user_table.*
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN user_table ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid
WHERE (jobs.groupid = ".$_SESSION['usergroup']." OR FIND_IN_SET('".$_SESSION['userid']."', jobs.extra_auth_users))
AND jobs.id = $id
AND (approved = 1 OR approved = 2 OR approved = 4);

//try 3
SELECT jobs.*, user_table.*
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN user_table ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid
WHERE (jobs.groupid = ".$_SESSION['usergroup']." OR FIND_IN_SET('".$_SESSION['userid']."', cast(jobs.extra_auth_users as char)) > 0)
AND jobs.id = $id
AND (approved = 1 OR approved = 2 OR approved = 4);
```

Comment: please help us by showing some table data, and also expand those variables into whatever string the database will eventually see

Comment: Which table contains `approved`?

Comment: BTW, it's generally better to write `approved IN (1, 2, 4)`. It's easier to read, and MySQL optimizes it better.

Comment: jobs table has approved

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` is the correct function to use. But it would be better if you normalized your design rather than using comma-separated lists.

Comment: What is the datatype of `extra_auth_users`? If it's already a string, why would you need to cast it to char?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any spaces in the comma-delimited string, `FIND_IN_SET` doesn't ignore them.

Comment: extra_auth_users is varchar

Comment: no spaces in that column

Comment: asking about approved made me wonder if it was even an approved job, and it wasn't, but after making it approved the 3rd try still doesn't work. will try the first 2 tries to see what happens.

Comment: no, none of the tries still work after approving job.

Comment: i accidentally erased the data in the new auth column for the other job i was testing and now it works. so after approving job and making sure the new column had data in it, the 2nd try works.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.